# Actualizar tabla en pagina principal al cerrar o actualizar popup

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, popup

Tengo la siguiente **duda** con un proyecto que llevo acabo.

Tengo una tabla en una pagina "***Principal***" y en esa tabla hago registros por hora y por registro tengo un CRUD, el simbolo de **"+" agrego** tiempos(registros) mediante un **modal**, en la lupa visualizo esos registros en un **Popup** que agrego mediante el **modal** y el otro es para eliminar el registro igual mediante un **modal**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El icono de la **lupa** me abre un **popup** en el cual tengo los registros que puedo **eliminar**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aqui viene mi DUDA...**

Existe la manera que yo al **elminar un registro** en mi popup me actualize mi tabla de la pagina principal sin necesidad de que yo tenga que **actualizar** por completo mi sitio.

```
$(".detalles").click( function() {
    $("#Line").val($(this).attr('data-id'));
    var url = "http://10.50.126.125/PSB_SMT/PopUpDetail.php?id=" + $("#Line").val();
    window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=center,left=center,width=900,height=500");
});
```

Codigo que elimina un registro en el popup

```
<?php
    $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','psb_smt');

    $idProdu=$_POST['idProdu'];
    $Minutos=$_POST['minutos'];
    $idProduLost=$_POST['idProduLost'];

        $sql1="UPDATE psb_smt.psb_produccion SET psb_tptreg = psb_tptreg -'$Minutos' WHERE id='$idProdu'";

        $sql="DELETE B FROM psb_smt.losttime B WHERE B.id = '$idProduLost'";

        echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1);
        echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    header('Location: PopUpDetail.php?id='.$idProdu.'');
?>
```

Comment: ¿Que utilizas para abrir la nueva ventana (_el popup_)?

Comment: puede que existe una forma , pero tendrás que agregar tu código, con el cual eliminas y cargas tu tabla, para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Listo ya anexe el codigo al post.

Comment: Ese es el código que abre el popup, pero tienes que poner el código que se ejecuta al hacer clic en "Eliminar". Lo interesante sería ver es cómo llamas al servidor, qué hace el servidor cuando le llamas, la consulta que haces para borrar el registro y que haces luego en el front cuando borras el registro.

Comment: Oh.. listo, ya modifique el post, el popup si me lo actualiza bien cuando borro un registro ya que pongo el header y me lo actualiza, solo quisiera que me actualizara la tabla que esta de fondo se podria decir como la ventana "madre" para tener la informacion actualizada siempre.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar cominucación a traves de [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

#### Ejemplo

En la ventana principal, suscribes una función al evento `onmessage`

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  // IMPORTANTE validar el origen
  if (event.origin !== "http://10.50.126.125") {
    return;
  }

  if (event.data.reload === true) {
    /* AQUI código para recargar */
  }
}, false);
</script>
```

En la ventana abierta, al borrar un registro guardas en una variable si es necesario (*o no*) recargar la ventana principal y, por ejemplo, al momento de cerrar/recargar la ventana (*`onbeforeunload`*) envías un mensaje con dicha información.

```
<script>
  let reloadParent = true; // AQUI indcamos si es necesario recargar
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
    // Enviamos un mensaje a la ventana padre
    window.opener.postMessage({ reload: reloadParent }, '*');
  }, false);
</script>
```